# Apache Airflow: How to cleanup DAGRun resources in a fool-proof way

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-2.x

In Apache Airflow 2.1, I want to create a temporary folder on a shared volume that all operators in a DAG can use to share files. I also want to delete the temporary folder after the DAG is done executing, whether it succeeded or not.

If I were to approach this by creating a new operator that a DAG author can use to create a temporary folder and return its path, I would also need to create a different, "cleanup" operator that the DAG author would need to also include in the DAG. Moreover, it would need to be wired in such a way that it is triggered even when something upstream fails (e.g. use the correct `trigger_rule`s). This leaves a lot of space for human error.

Is there a way to "defer" a cleanup operation transparently, without requiring the DAG author to manually schedule the cleanup? Perhaps a DAG subclass, or a decorator, or an Operator that somehow defers an operation? I know about [triggers](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/deferring.html#), but did not find a way to utilize them for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by using an operator like [TimeDeltaSensorAsync](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.4.0/_api/airflow/sensors/time_delta/index.html), [TimeDeltaSensor](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.4.0/_api/airflow/sensors/time_delta/index.html), [DateTimeSensorAsync](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.4.0/_api/airflow/sensors/date_time/index.html) or [DateTimeSensor](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.4.0/_api/airflow/sensors/date_time/index.html) to wait until the time to cleanup has come, followed by the actual cleanup task.

If you want to run to run the cleanup only in case of success you can simply place the wait task at the end of the DAG. If you want to run it whether the DAG succeeded or not you can place it right after the start of the DAG or at the end of the dag with the [trigger rule "none_skipped"](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.4.0/concepts/dags.html#trigger-rules).

An example of such a structure would look something like this:

```py
with DAG(...) as dag:
    last_task = ...

    task_wait_cleanup = TimeDeltaSensorAsync(
        task_id = ...,
        delta = datetime.timedelta(days=...),
        trigger_rule = "none_skipped"
    )
    last_task >> task_wait_cleanup

    task_cleanup = BashOperator(
        task_id = ...,
        bash_command = 'rm -r "$dagRunTempDir"',
        env = { "dagRunTempDir": ... }
    )
    task_wait_cleanup >> task_cleanup
```

You can see a real-world example of this [here](https://gitlab.com/openetymologymap/open-etymology-map/-/blob/v2.16.10/init/OemDbInitDAG.py#L1013).